# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject single item vs multiple item

Tags: c#, json

Found out that serialize XML object with single item and multiple item gives me different format, thus accessing it would be different.

For example, with single item:

```
{
    "schemalist": {
        "schema": {
            "fieldid": "email",
            "displayname": "email",            
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "schemalist": {
        "schema": [
            {
                "fieldid": "name",
                "displayname": "name",                
            },
            {
                "fieldid": "email",
                "displayname": "email",                
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

so when I parse them jQuery.ParseJSON, I have to access them differently

schemalist.schema.fieldid
and
schemalist.schema[0].fieldid

is there a way to convert to json even with single item, so I can use
schemalist.schema[0].fieldid even across single, multiple items?

thanks!

Edit:
Here's my xml input:

```
<schemalist>
<schema>
    <fieldid><![CDATA[name]]></fieldid>
    <displayname><![CDATA[name]]></displayname>        
</schema>
<schema>
    <fieldid><![CDATA[email]]></fieldid>
    <displayname><![CDATA[email]]></displayname>        
</schema>
```

but sometimes the return could have only one schema:

```
<schemalist>    
<schema>
    <fieldid><![CDATA[email]]></fieldid>
    <displayname><![CDATA[email]]></displayname>        
</schema>    
</schemalist>
```

then I would do my conversion like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
```

Comment: if you use a list, doesn't it always use it as an array? like `[]`

Comment: Do you have some sample inputs?

Comment: Why do you want schemalist.schema[0].fieldid and not schemalist[0].schema[0].fieldid? Seems inconsistent doesn't it?  In answer to the question though, the structure of the C# object mirrors the structure of the JSON. If you want to change that I'd advise transforming the C# object after you've converted from JSON, using whatever rules you want to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, what i end up doing was to remove the property and then add it again.

```
// run the code below with $(schemalist.schemalist.schema).length == 1
// create a schema array 
var schema = [];
schema.push(schemalist.schemalist.schema);

// delete the property
delete schemalist.schemalist.schema;
schemalist['schema'] = schema;
```

so instead of accessing properties fieldid:
schemalist.schema.fieldid,

I can use
schemalist.schema[i].fieldid

even with one element, ha!